# AMP script error with conditional statement "The initial end count value for the for loop could not be cast to an integer."

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm getting the error

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
> The initial end count value for the for loop could not be cast to an integer.

when trying to go to preview and test in marketing cloud

```
%%[
 var @rows, @rowCount, @vendedorEmail
    set @vendedorEmail = Email
    set @rows = LookupRows("felipevendedores", "Email", @vendedorEmail)
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
]%%


     %%[
     IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
 
     FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO
     set @row = ROW(@rows,@i)
 
     var @contactId, @clientName, @clientEmail 
     set @contactId = FIELD(@row,'ContactId') 
     set @clientName= field(@row,"Nome_Cliente") 
     set @clientEmail = field(@row,"Email_Cliente")
     
     set @celular = field(@row,"Celular_Cliente") 
         IF EMPTY(@celular) THEN 
         set @celular = 'Não informado'
     ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing and `endif` and `next @i`.  I'd suggest you wrap your send context assignments with [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

```
%%[ 

    set @vendedorEmail = AttributeValue("Email")
    set @rows = LookupRows("felipevendedores", "Email", @vendedorEmail) 
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

]%%

%%[

 IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO

         set @row = ROW(@rows,@i)
         set @contactId = FIELD(@row,'ContactId') 
         set @clientName= field(@row,"Nome_Cliente") 
         set @clientEmail = field(@row,"Email_Cliente")
         set @celular = field(@row,"Celular_Cliente") 

         IF EMPTY(@celular) THEN 
            set @celular = 'Não informado'
         ENDIF

]%%
  <!-- HTML HERE -->
%%[

    next @i 

endif

]%%
```